# A well order on a subset of a power set

Tags: order-theory

I'm struggling with one problem which touches upon ordering of a power set.

Assume I have a well order $\langle X,\preceq\rangle$ where $|X|=|\mathbb{R}|$. Is it possible to find (i.e. give a construction) a well ordering on an uncountable subset of $\langle P(X),\subseteq\rangle$? There is a well order there, that I know, but is there a way to explicitly show where it is? We might as well use $\langle P(\mathbb{R}),\subseteq\rangle$, but I can't come up with any well order there.

Perhaps you've got some hints?

Comment: Not in general. You can not find a well-ordering on $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})$ from a well-ordering on $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: I doesn't have to be on the whole $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})$, I'm fine with some subordering.

Comment: If you find a sub-well-ordered subset, you can find it by just taking some finite linearly ordered subset.

Comment: You're right, absolutely. But I'm actually trying to find something isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$, so it's gotta be uncountable. (I edited the question, sorry for the imprecision.)

Comment: I think the set of initial segments is fit for your question.

Comment: Sooo... $\emptyset$ would be the least element in every subset?

Comment: If you have a well-ordering of $X$ then you should be able to define a well-ordering of the set of all one-element subsets of $X.$ Was there some other condition you wanted your well-ordering to satisfy?

Comment: @bof but OP assumes the ordering is the inclusion.

Comment: @Jules right. Empty set is the least initial segment.

Comment: @HanulJeon I wondered if that was what he wanted, but he didn't say so.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Every partial order embeds into its power set. Moreover this embedding is only cardinality dependent. So if $|A|\leq|B|$, every partial order of $A$ embeds into $\langle\mathcal P(B),\subseteq\rangle$.

To see this, if $\langle A,\leq\rangle$ is a partial order, $a\mapsto\{a'\in A\mid a'\leq a\}$ is an order embedding.

So yes, if $X$ is an uncountable well-ordered set, it embeds into its power set. The assumption that $|X|=|\Bbb R|$ is entirely irrelevant here.

Comment: Thanks for redirecting me here. However, I don't see why the assumption that $ A $ is a well order is relevant with this argument.

Comment: It's not relevant. It is a consequence, and a trivial one.